# Demonstrate object key value according to input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to link my js vanilla code with json. I want to show value of object key that input in the search box. I add an example image of what i want. Thanks
[image of result type that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV0VD.png)

My basic html and script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sono brillo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <input id = "userInput" > <br> <br>
   <button onclick="myFunction()" > Run </button>
   <h1 id="message"> </h1>

   <style>
       body{background-color: darkblue; text-align: center; color: floralwhite;}

   </style>
   <script>
        function myFunction() {

            let userInput = document.querySelector("#userInput");
            let message = document.querySelector("#message");

            message.innerHTML = userInput.value;
}

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my json

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ELIw__G5fXP3OZVTd-AZ9tu7YjzL-2G9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing? There are multiple ways to go about it. You can hit the API server and get the JSON, load the complete JSON in-memory and assign to a variable, and then perform a lookup over the variable.

Comment: @KanishkAnand i dont know but i could not do it maybe i need some codes. Thanks